# Codigo Fuente de Redux-Thunk : ¿ A quien hace referencia el next?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Estoy tratando de comprender el codigo fuente de redux-thunk , ya que esta es una libreria que nos permite aplicar un midleware de manera pero facil , pero no entendia muy bien que hacia por detras:

el codigo fuente de thunk es el siguiente:

```
function createThunkMiddleware(extraArgument) {
    return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
     if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
        } 
     return next(action);
      }; 
    }
   const thunk = createThunkMiddleware();
   thunk.withExtraArgument = createThunkMiddleware; 
   export default thunk;
```

Si bien logro comprender que si la actionCreator retorna una functión entonces está devuelve =>
`return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);`
Me gustaria comprender que es lo que sucede con esta parte de la función, ¿a que hace referencia ese next?

```
return next(action);
```

Comment: Necesitás acudir a la propia [documentación de Redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#writing-custom-middleware) para comprender su funcionamiento.

Comment: Leí esa documentación y lo que habia anotado es lo siguiente:  [Next() hace referencia al siguiente middleware en proceso. Si este middleware es el último de la secuencia, en next en realidad hará un dispatch(action)]